# ++i operator in Python

Tags: java, python

I'm trying to translate one of my Java projects to Python and I'm having trouble with one certain line. The Java code is:

```
if (++j == 9)
    return true;
```

What I think this is supposed to be in python is

```
if (j += 1) ==9:
        return True
```

...but I am getting an error `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

How can I translate this Java to Python?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, that is indeed a syntax error.

You probably want:

```
j += 1
if j == 9:
  return True
```

The reason is because python requires an *expression* after the `if` keyword ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-if-statement)), whereas `j += 1` is a *statement*.

---

And congratulations, you've just dodged a bullet - by not translating it to:

```
if (++j == 9):
    return True
```

which *is valid python code*, and would almost certainly be a bug!

Comment: Hopefully nobody would use parentheses in an `if` like that :)

Comment: +1 for the valid Python code example that doesn't do what a new Python programmer might expect (I was caught by that some years back).

Answer (score 1):

Just break it up into two lines since Python doesn't have the `++` operator.

```
j += 1
if j == 9:
  return True
```

As wim has pointed out, and `if` statement requires something that evaluates to a True or False value.  In Java, the `++j` portion will be evaluated before the comparison.  Then the new `j` value will be compared thus resulting in a true or false expression.

Answer (score 0):

The ++ operator does not exist in Python. Instead you could do:

```
j += 1
if j == 9:
    return True
```

Comment: The return is not equivalent.

Comment: This would not execute any code that's (possibly) after the `if`.

Comment: Correct, I've changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The += operator is an assignment operator. Assignment operators need to be run separately from your conditional statement. You should run the code like this:

```
j+=1
if j==9:
   return True
```

Answer (score 0):

- There are no `++` (or `--`) operators in Python.
- `j += 1` doesn't return a value so there is nothing to compare.

It looks like you want:

```
if j == 8:
    return True
```

If `j` is `global` (usually frowned upon), then:

```
j += 1
if j == 9:
    return True
```

Answer (score 0):

`j += 1` is equivalent to `j = j + 1`. It doesn't actually return a value, but just overwrites the variable `j`. I'm presuming you want to see if `j + 1 == 9`, so replace:

```
if (j += 1) ==9:
    return True
```

With:

```
j += 1
if j == 9:
    return True
```